# Copy data from GCP to Azure Storage when the bucket in GCP has a requester pays

Tags: azure, google-cloud-platform, bucket

I am trying to copy data from GCP to Azure Storage, but the bucket in GCP has a Requester Pays, I did try the transfer using AzCopy and Azure Data Factory, at the end of the Azure configuration I can see the bucket in GCP but when hit the bucket I got a 400 bad request error, this is because the bucket in GCP has a requester pays, what additional configuration I have to do to copy the data? I already have the credential of the GCP service account

Comment: What service account are you using (the one you have credentials for)? Is it from the same project as the bucker?

Comment: Yes, it is from the same project as the bucket!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you will be able to use AzCopy.  Looking at the GCP documentation on Requester Pays, you need to send the billing `PROJECT_IDENTIFIER` along with the request.  There are several ways to do this.  I would suggest looking at the REST API or the code samples.

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/using-requester-pays#code-samples_2

**Azure Data Factory** supports pulling data from a REST API so you could use the GCP REST call with it.  Just make sure you send the billing `PROJECT_IDENTIFIER` along with your REST call.

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/using-requester-pays#rest-access-requester-pays